# Linux memory usage higher than sum of processes

Tags: linux, memory

I'm trying to figure out what is eating my memory. I'm speculating that if it's not used by userspace processes then it may be from the kernel side.

There is the output from some commands. I know that Linux is using copy-on-write so expected memory usage should be 514MB or less (shared segments are just 7.75 MB in total). free -m is reporting that it is used 2804 MB. I tried to eat it with python and it indeed started swaping when it was used more than 7324 MB (reported by free -m). So how can I find out what is using 2804-514 MB of ram? I didn't find any easy method to break down used memory by kernel modules.

Basic system info: Linux Mint 17, thinkpad T530 with BTRFS filesystem.

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7669       4055       3614         66          0       1250
-/+ buffers/cache:       2804       4864
Swap:         5367          0       5367


$ ipcs -m|tail -n +4|awk '{sum+=$5} END {print sum / 1024/1024}'
7.75

$ sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd  | awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum / 1024}'
514.43

$ smem -twk
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0
kernel image                      0          0          0
kernel dynamic memory          3.6G       1.2G       2.3G
userspace memory             412.3M      52.6M     359.7M
free memory                    3.5G       3.5G          0
----------------------------------------------------------
                               7.5G       4.8G       2.7G
```

meminfo (note, that numbers are in MB)

```
cat /proc/meminfo |awk '{print $1"\t"($2/1024)"\t"$3}'
MemTotal:       7669.72 kB
MemFree:        3615.05 kB
Buffers:        0.078125        kB
Cached: 1250.41 kB
SwapCached:     0       kB
Active: 825.223 kB
Inactive:       781.68  kB
Active(anon):   124.059 kB
Inactive(anon): 298.477 kB
Active(file):   701.164 kB
Inactive(file): 483.203 kB
Unevictable:    0       kB
Mlocked:        0       kB
SwapTotal:      5367.33 kB
SwapFree:       5367.33 kB
Dirty:  0       kB
Writeback:      0       kB
AnonPages:      356.391 kB
Mapped: 52.7031 kB
Shmem:  66.1211 kB
Slab:   100.266 kB
SReclaimable:   54.0039 kB
SUnreclaim:     46.2617 kB
KernelStack:    3.35156 kB
PageTables:     18.0586 kB
NFS_Unstable:   0       kB
Bounce: 0       kB
WritebackTmp:   0       kB
CommitLimit:    9202.19 kB
Committed_AS:   1343.93 kB
VmallocTotal:   3.35544e+07     kB
VmallocUsed:    352.312 kB
VmallocChunk:   3.35541e+07     kB
HardwareCorrupted:      0       kB
AnonHugePages:  58      kB
HugePages_Total:        0
HugePages_Free: 0
HugePages_Rsvd: 0
HugePages_Surp: 0
Hugepagesize:   2       kB
DirectMap4k:    294.938 kB
DirectMap2M:    7578    kB
```

unaltered meminfo and other requested info (note that some time passed since the first batch of the info, but I tried to make it as same as possible)

```
sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | awk '{sum+=$2} END {print sum / 1024}'
518.551

$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7669       4155       3513         68          0       1202
-/+ buffers/cache:       2953       4716
Swap:         5367          0       5367

$ sudo slabtop -o -s c
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 344353 / 409584 (84.1%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 12149 / 12149 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 80 / 112 (71.4%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 92748.52K / 105317.22K (88.1%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.26K / 15.75K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME               
 13371  13371 100%    1.04K    452       30     14464K btrfs_inode        
 56280  49088  87%    0.19K   2680       21     10720K dentry             
 17010  14121  83%    0.55K    627       28     10032K radix_tree_node    
 10175   9575  94%    0.63K    407       25      6512K proc_inode_cache   
 29652  19386  65%    0.19K   1412       21      5648K kmalloc-192        
  9856   9452  95%    0.57K    352       28      5632K inode_cache        
   745    481  64%    5.98K    149        5      4768K task_struct        
  1104   1068  96%    4.00K    138        8      4416K kmalloc-4096       
 11200  11018  98%    0.31K    448       25      3584K btrfs_extent_buffer
  1746   1679  96%    2.00K    110       16      3520K kmalloc-2048       
 30096  30048  99%    0.11K    836       36      3344K sysfs_dir_cache    
 43456  23262  53%    0.06K    679       64      2716K kmalloc-64         
 10368   7228  69%    0.25K    324       32      2592K kmalloc-256        
  2144   1911  89%    1.00K     67       32      2144K kmalloc-1024       
 13650   9943  72%    0.15K    525       26      2100K btrfs_extent_map   
  2013   2013 100%    0.96K     61       33      1952K ext4_inode_cache   
  3040   2472  81%    0.50K     95       32      1520K kmalloc-512        
  2232   1938  86%    0.66K     93       24      1488K shmem_inode_cache  
  1755   1735  98%    0.81K     45       39      1440K task_xstate        
  1584   1584 100%    0.88K     44       36      1408K mm_struct          
  1026    886  86%    1.06K     36       30      1152K signal_cache        
   525    442  84%    2.06K     35       15      1120K sighand_cache      
   133    127  95%    8.00K     34        4      1088K kmalloc-8192        
  7744   6829  88%    0.12K    242       32       968K kmalloc-128         
 14720  14260  96%    0.06K    230       64       920K ext4_free_data      
  8610   6966  80%    0.09K    205       42       820K btrfs_extent_state 
 12736   6989  54%    0.06K    199       64       796K anon_vma           
  1225   1069  87%    0.62K     49       25       784K sock_inode_cache   
   345    345 100%    2.06K     23       15       736K idr_layer_cache    
  2254   1321  58%    0.29K     84       27       672K btrfs_delayed_node 
 18688  14340  76%    0.03K    146      128       584K kmalloc-32         
  3870   3870 100%    0.13K    129       30       516K ext4_allocation_context
  4875   4647  95%    0.10K    125       39       500K buffer_head        
  6272   6272 100%    0.07K    112       56       448K Acpi-ParseExt      
   252    163  64%    1.75K     14       18       448K TCP                
  1155   1155 100%    0.37K     55       21       440K btrfs_ordered_extent
  4116   4116 100%    0.09K     98       42       392K kmalloc-96         
  4140   4140 100%    0.09K     90       46       360K ext4_xattr         
  4539   4539 100%    0.08K     89       51       356K btrfs_prelim_ref   
  1050    907  86%    0.31K     42       25       336K mnt_cache          
   882    647  73%    0.38K     42       21       336K blkdev_requests

$ top -n 1 -o %MEM

top - 19:38:58 up 2 days,  4:48, 21 users,  load average: 0.07, 0.09, 0.13
Tasks: 267 total,   1 running, 266 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.1 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.5 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   7853796 total,  4270896 used,  3582900 free,       60 buffers
KiB Swap:  5496148 total,        0 used,  5496148 free.  1238332 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                
 1710 root      20   0  450176  37480  23708 S   6.3  0.5  23:25.64 Xorg                                                   
 3233 loj       20   0  564556  37128   8868 S   6.3  0.5   4:15.48 xfce4-terminal                                         
 1889 root      20   0  182980  33740   1500 S   0.0  0.4   0:04.07 puppet                                                 
 2604 loj       20   0  457136  29468   3096 S   0.0  0.4   0:08.20 xfdesktop                                              
 2398 root      20   0  926976  28652   1244 S   0.0  0.4   1:01.01 docker.io                                              
 2605 loj       20   0  421612  24312   2612 S   0.0  0.3   1:00.18 redshift-gtk                                           
 2634 loj       20   0  568552  21900   5252 S   0.0  0.3   0:03.30 mintUpdate                                             
 2919 loj       20   0  483152  12052   4608 S   0.0  0.2   0:05.71 panel-7-indicat                                        
 2742 loj       20   0  545364  11548   5864 S   0.0  0.1   0:06.72 panel-1-whisker                                        
 2600 loj       20   0  487296  11444   5264 S   0.0  0.1   0:43.00 xfce4-panel                                            
 2645 loj       20   0  248504  10576   1408 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.92 applet.py                                              
 2596 loj       20   0  167352   9924   4176 S   0.0  0.1   2:47.19 xfwm4                                                  
 2628 loj       20   0  683744   9776   3352 S   0.0  0.1   0:15.63 nm-applet                                              
 2616 loj       20   0  382528   6832   3388 S   0.0  0.1   0:11.27 xfce4-power-man                                        
 2872 loj       20   0  382416   5944   1636 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.91 gvfs-udisks2-vo                                        
10166 root      20   0  358828   5840   1884 S   0.0  0.1   0:16.78 NetworkManager                                         
 1099 root      20   0  295828   5556   1272 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.56 polkitd                                                
 2923 loj       20   0  164404   5348   3008 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.78 panel-5-datetim                                        
14257 loj       20   0   25384   5340   1768 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.12 bash                                                   
20503 loj       20   0   25380   5340   1772 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.16 bash                                                   
17690 loj       20   0   25396   5328   1748 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 bash                                                   
18732 loj       20   0   25396   5328   1744 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 bash                                                   
18538 loj       20   0   25396   5324   1740 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.04 bash                                                   
16501 loj       20   0   25380   5308   1744 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.06 bash                                                   
27045 loj       20   0   26316   5100    592 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.87 bash                                                   
 2913 loj       20   0  149164   5096   3132 S   0.0  0.1   0:11.82 panel-4-genmon                                         
28187 loj       20   0   25396   5028   1440 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.09 bash                                                   
 2917 loj       20   0  149160   4996   3036 S   0.0  0.1   0:29.28 panel-9-genmon                                         
16558 loj       20   0   26160   4948    592 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.02 bash                                                   
 2641 loj        9 -11  371060   4940   2532 S   0.0  0.1  13:13.11 pulseaudio                                             
 2904 loj       20   0   26100   4884    592 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.21 bash                                                   
12720 loj       20   0   26076   4856    592 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.25 bash                                                   
19240 loj       20   0   25572   4844   1156 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.18 bash                                                   
11583 loj       20   0   25380   4708   1140 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 bash                                                   
18425 loj       20   0   25508   4692   1044 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.08 bash                                                   
 4865 loj       20   0   25368   4556    996 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.30 bash                                                   
11552 loj       20   0   25384   4516    944 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.05 bash                                                   
 6966 loj       20   0   51180   4332   1620 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.15 vim                                                    
 2888 root      20   0  451912   4288   1624 S   0.0  0.1   0:28.69 udisksd                               
11310 loj       20   0   25452   4216    592 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.20 bash
 2679 loj       20   0  343428   4196   1752 S   0.0  0.1   0:02.56 xfsettingsd
31494 loj       20   0   25380   4164    596 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.16 bash



$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        7853796 kB
MemFree:         3593092 kB
Buffers:              60 kB
Cached:          1237532 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           667844 kB
Inactive:         934244 kB
Active(anon):      28480 kB
Inactive(anon):   412756 kB
Active(file):     639364 kB
Inactive(file):   521488 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       5496148 kB
SwapFree:        5496148 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        364556 kB
Mapped:            48308 kB
Shmem:             76740 kB
Slab:             107128 kB
SReclaimable:      61012 kB
SUnreclaim:        46116 kB
KernelStack:        3344 kB
PageTables:        18088 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9423044 kB
Committed_AS:    1382404 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      360768 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359364252 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     61440 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      304064 kB
DirectMap2M:     7757824 kB

$ sudo cat /proc/vmstat 
nr_free_pages 807707
nr_alloc_batch 3485
nr_inactive_anon 103817
nr_active_anon 14695
nr_inactive_file 157126
nr_active_file 183051
nr_unevictable 0
nr_mlock 0
nr_anon_pages 96859
nr_mapped 19398
nr_file_pages 361889
nr_dirty 0
nr_writeback 0
nr_slab_reclaimable 16123
nr_slab_unreclaimable 11793
nr_page_table_pages 4772
nr_kernel_stack 429
nr_unstable 0
nr_bounce 0
nr_vmscan_write 100293
nr_vmscan_immediate_reclaim 3432
nr_writeback_temp 0
nr_isolated_anon 0
nr_isolated_file 0
nr_shmem 21712
nr_dirtied 55931244
nr_written 55847537
numa_hit 335064087
numa_miss 0
numa_foreign 0
numa_interleave 24522
numa_local 335064087
numa_other 0
nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 28
nr_free_cma 0
nr_dirty_threshold 111416
nr_dirty_background_threshold 55708
pgpgin 129334306
pgpgout 233190636
pswpin 80715
pswpout 100268
pgalloc_dma 0
pgalloc_dma32 159890087
pgalloc_normal 257522463
pgalloc_movable 0
pgfree 424750256
pgactivate 23419593
pgdeactivate 11177646
pgfault 508757717
pgmajfault 19562
pgrefill_dma 0
pgrefill_dma32 3369566
pgrefill_normal 7975279
pgrefill_movable 0
pgsteal_kswapd_dma 0
pgsteal_kswapd_dma32 20040131
pgsteal_kswapd_normal 34430518
pgsteal_kswapd_movable 0
pgsteal_direct_dma 0
pgsteal_direct_dma32 1161023
pgsteal_direct_normal 1344398
pgsteal_direct_movable 0
pgscan_kswapd_dma 0
pgscan_kswapd_dma32 20077734
pgscan_kswapd_normal 34646412
pgscan_kswapd_movable 0
pgscan_direct_dma 0
pgscan_direct_dma32 1164470
pgscan_direct_normal 1414283
pgscan_direct_movable 0
pgscan_direct_throttle 0
zone_reclaim_failed 0
pginodesteal 63
slabs_scanned 2262272
kswapd_inodesteal 168
kswapd_low_wmark_hit_quickly 107411
kswapd_high_wmark_hit_quickly 94396
pageoutrun 231397
allocstall 37862
pgrotated 113947
numa_pte_updates 0
numa_huge_pte_updates 0
numa_hint_faults 0
numa_hint_faults_local 0
numa_pages_migrated 0
pgmigrate_success 2038063
pgmigrate_fail 3670
compact_migrate_scanned 18509229
compact_free_scanned 464282669
compact_isolated 9111435
compact_stall 3146
compact_fail 2215
compact_success 931
htlb_buddy_alloc_success 0
htlb_buddy_alloc_fail 0
unevictable_pgs_culled 0
unevictable_pgs_scanned 0
unevictable_pgs_rescued 6
unevictable_pgs_mlocked 6
unevictable_pgs_munlocked 6
unevictable_pgs_cleared 0
unevictable_pgs_stranded 0
thp_fault_alloc 5220
thp_fault_fallback 7309
thp_collapse_alloc 2740
thp_collapse_alloc_failed 1229
thp_split 2320
thp_zero_page_alloc 3
thp_zero_page_alloc_failed 0
nr_tlb_remote_flush 1119474
nr_tlb_remote_flush_received 1416528
nr_tlb_local_flush_all 3215771
nr_tlb_local_flush_one 161032407

$ sudo cat /proc/loadavg 
0.52 0.35 0.27 2/1124 22236
```

Comment: one process can uses all free memory, any way use top

Comment: I would suggest you provide an unaltered meminfo. Also provide details of the host itself (if it is a virtual machine, etc).

Comment: what about `sudo slabtop -o`?

Comment: Hi all, added info from top, unaltered meminfo, basic system info and output from slabtop sorted by cache size (afaik this is Slab: in /proc/meminfo)

Comment: One more thing? `cat /proc/vmstat` ? Doesn't look like slab is using more than 10% of your "missing" 2GB.

Comment: @CedricKnight added at the end (btw, I don't understand anything reported from there)

Comment: Please provide the output of `/proc/loadavg`

Comment: @MatthewIfe Added at the end

Comment: This is a big guess, but you have 1124 tasks but 267 processes. It *could* be (probably unlikely though) that these threads (which have their own stack) take up a lots of stack space. These will not be accounted for in the count you are doing. Its unusual for this to be the case unless many threads are allocating large chunks of stack memory.

Comment: To the OP: thanks: most nr_* fields of vmstat are in 4K pages, File being cache, Anon being RSS, and almost all kernel being Slab. @Matthew Ife : yes, some hand-compiled multi-threaded executables can reserve masses of user stack, but wouldn't that show in both RSS and Anon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very much like a kernel memory leak.  I'd roughly expect File+Anon+Free+Slab to add to your total physical RAM, but it's 2-3 GB short.  If you've been doing a lot of disk-intensive work, maybe it's BTRFS (example [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.btrfs/40824)).  You'd need a kernel with kmemleak enabled to check.

Comment: Well, very interesting. I was testing the tasks I did in that 2 days. Memory usage increased after docker build image. Then I did dd image with ext4 placed on btrfs for /var/lib/docker. Memory usage still increased. After I moved that ext4 dd image on ext4 (another disk) then memory usage didn't increased after docker build. So probably it's indeed memory leak from btrfs. I will upgrade the kernel and see what happens.

Comment: Upgrading Linux Mint from 17 to 17.1 and kernel to 3.16.0-30-generic resolved that issue :)

Comment: Good to know you have it fixed, and reassuring to know it's not a new bug (it looks like the one I linked to isn't fixed until 3.19).  Feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: I know this was asked quite some years ago :-) , but I am facing a similar issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621512/cannot-find-memory-usage-in-kubernetes-cluster-node and also my Active + free +Slab memory does not add to total. I also cannot find the used memory anywhere. Could it be a leak as well?